# Create solid separator

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have looked around quite a bit and cannot find the solution.

I am adding a separator in `SceneBuilder`.  This is easy.  Now I want this separator to be a `solid` line.

This I am having issues with.  I have tried :

```css
-fx-border-style: solid;
-fx-border-width: 1px;
```

But this doesn't seem to work or any combination of this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i think you missed line part in below css

```
.separator *.line { 
-fx-border-style: solid;
-fx-border-width: 1px;

}
```

with boarder width 5px

[image]

**Tip** : use **CSS Analayzer** to know css class/selector for particular part of node, you can find css analyzer in **scenebuilder 1.1** `view -> Show css Analyzer` or `ctrl+6` shortcut in windows.

Comment: Thanks! got it to work.  Thanks for the tip regarding the `CSS Analyzer`.

Comment: I can't seem to get a 1px border. Smallest that gets rendered seems to be a 2px border.

Comment: @crush: I guess because the border is on both sides (1+1).

Answer (score 14):

Its the solution of your problem, which was my problem too:

```
.separator *.line {
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0; /* its make really one-pixel-border */
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me. I finally gave it a negative padding as I noticed the divider forms a rectangle and it worked like a charm.

```
.separator *.line{
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-padding: 0 -50 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to change *all* of my separators, just that one, so I needed it as a custom class (chose `"blackSeparator"` here). Additionally I found out that I don't need the `*` wildcard and the pixel-width needs to be `0.5px` to get it 1 pixel width.

The solution:

```css
    .blackSeparator.separator .line {
        -fx-border-width: 0.5px;
        -fx-border-color: black;
    }
```